# Parsing of .env files natively in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

I know that NodeJS does not read the `.env` files automatically, but is there some native module for the parsing of `.env` files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answers for the one month for the popular tag "node.js" means "There is no such native functionality".